# How can I make empty tags self-closing with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I've created an XML template in ERB. I fill it in with data from a database during an export process.

In some cases, there is a null value, in which case an element may be empty, like this:

```
<someitem>

</someitem>
```

In that case, the client receiving the export wants it to be converted into a self-closing tag:

```
<someitem/>
```

I'm trying to see how to get Nokogiri to do this, but I don't see it yet. Does anybody know how to make empty XML tags self-closing with Nokogiri?

### Update

A regex was sufficient to do what I specified above, but the client now also wants tags whose children are all empty to be self-closing. So this:

```
<someitem>
  <subitem>

  </subitem>
  <subitem>

  </subitem>
</someitem>
```

... should also be

```
<someitem/>
```

I think that this will require using Nokogiri.

Comment: I do not understand your updated self-closing rule. It seems that you're suggesting that nodes with no content (`subitem`) should be removed. If this is the case, though, then after removing them the parent (`someitem`) should also be removed, as it too will have no content.

Answer (score 5):

Search for

```
<([^>]+)>\s*</\1>
```

and replace with

```
<\1/>
```

In Ruby:

```
result = subject.gsub(/<([^>]+)>\s*<\/\1>/, '<\1/>')
```

**Explanation:**

```
<       # Match opening bracket
(       # Match and remember...
 [^>]+  # One or more characters except >
)       # End of capturing group
>       # Match closing bracket
\s*     # Match optional whitespace & newlines
<       # Match opening bracket
/       # Match /
\1      # Match the contents of the opening tag
>       # Match closing bracket
```

Comment: This is the easiest thing for me to drop in conditionally in the export process. Thanks!

Comment: @MattHuggins: Your edit doesn't make much sense. `\n` is already contained in `\s`, so `[\s\n]` is exactly the same as `\s`. But the previous edit already was strange (for kind of the same reasons), so I think the answer should be reverted to its original form. What do you think?

Comment: @TimPietzcker - I didn't realize that `\n` is already included `\s`.  The first edit is what inspired my second edit.  If what you say is true, then I agree reverting to the original answer is probably for the best.  (It might be worth updating the explanation for `\s*` to make it clear that this includes whitespace & newlines.)

Comment: I've gone ahead & reverted with a note that `\s` includes newlines. :)  Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1):

A couple questions:

1. `<foo></foo>` is the same as `<foo />`, so why worry about such a tiny detail? If it is syntactically significant because the text node between the two is a `"\n"`, then put a test in your ERB template that checks for the value that would go there, and if it's not initialized output the self-closing tag instead? See "[Yak shaving](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving)".
2. Why involve Nokogiri? You should be able to generate correct XML in ERB since you're in control of the template.

EDIT - Nokogiri's behavior is to not-rewrite parsed XML unless it has to. I suspect you'd have to remove the node in question, then reinsert it as an empty node to get Nokogiri to output what you want.

Comment: I heartily agree with your first point. It's the client who receives the export who has asked for this change.

Comment: Then just do it in ERB. A second pass through Nokogiri is a lot of extra processing without a lot of added benefit.

Comment: You make a good point, but since this **is** kind of a "yak-shaving" request, and I don't think other clients will care, I am trying to do it conditionally in the export task for this client. The conditional logic would be easier to put in one place there than in multiple places in the template. And the processing overhead isn't a big deal, since this code will be run something like once a month, and if it takes 30 seconds or 10 minutes, I don't really care.

Comment: When I have a conditional string I need to output multiple times in ERB, I either predefine it in my controller, or, I'll create it at the top of the template and assign it to a variable, then reference the variable throughout the document. For example, things like paging in reports where its the same thing at the top and bottom.

Comment: Is there some reason that after 3 years someone is flagging this? The questions were rhetorical.