# Creating a <source> element without a closing tag in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, nokogiri

Using Nokogiri, I am manually creating `<video>` and `<source>` tags. My code looks like this:

```
mp4_source_tag = html.create_element('source')
tag.replace(mp4_source_tag)          
mp4_source_tag['type'] = 'video/mp4'
mp4_source_tag['src'] = video.mp4_video.url
```

Which produces the following HTML:

`<source type="video/mp4" src="/system/mp4_videos/1/original/trailer.mp4?1347088365"></source>`

However this is invalid HTML5. The correct output should be:

`<source type="video/mp4" src="/system/mp4_videos/1/original/trailer.mp4?1347088365">`

How would I use Nokogiri to output valid HTML5 without the closing `</source>` tag?

The replaced tag was an `<img>` tag, but that doesn't appear to matter.

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459832/how-can-i-make-empty-tags-self-closing-with-nokogiri

Comment: It's _invalid_ to close the tag? What kind of design decision was that?

Comment: @MarkThomas An odd one, especially given that it's legal to have a closing slash. _"Start tags consist of [...] optionally a "/" character, **which may be present only if the element is a void element**. [...] Void elements only have a start tag; **end tags must not be specified for void elements**."_ See [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements) for more information.

Comment: The source tag _is_ a void element. So why can't you use the self-closing form: `<source ... />`?

Answer (score 0):

If you create your document as XML instead of HTML, Nokogiri will output empty elements with a closing slash, e.g. `<source />`; this is valid for HTML5.

```
html = Nokogiri.HTML('')
puts html.create_element('source')
#=> <source></source>

xml = Nokogiri.XML('')
puts xml.create_element('source')
#=> <source/>
```

The downsides of this, however, is that parsing a valid HTML5 document as XML will cause mistakes in parsing:

```
require 'nokogiri'
html5 = '<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head><body>
    <img src="a.jpg"><img src="b.jpg">
  </body></html>'
doc = Nokogiri.XML( html5, &:noblanks )
puts doc
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <!DOCTYPE html>
#=> <html>
#=>   <head>
#=>     <meta charset="utf-8">
#=>       <title>Test</title>
#=>     </meta>
#=>     <body>
#=>       <img src="a.jpg">
#=>         <img src="b.jpg">
#=>   </img>
#=>       </img>
#=>     </body>
#=>   </head>
#=> </html>
```

To fix this, you'll need to make your source be valid XML by self-closing your void elements (which is also valid for HTML5). Further, to avoid the XML Declaration you'll need to serialize the DTD and root separately:

```
require 'nokogiri'
html5 = '<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head><body>
    <img src="a.jpg"/><img src="b.jpg"/>
  </body></html>'
doc = Nokogiri.XML( html5, &:noblanks )
puts doc.children.map(&:to_s)
#=> <!DOCTYPE html>
#=> <html>
#=>   <head>
#=>     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
#=>     <title>Test</title>
#=>   </head>
#=>   <body>
#=>     <img src="a.jpg"/>
#=>     <img src="b.jpg"/>
#=>   </body>
#=> </html>
```